# How do I make the "back button" work with jQuery hide/show functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to append text to the url with jQuery so that the back button is not broken when a user loads new content with jQuery.

For example, I have a three step form - the first step is (www.xyz.com/form-1).  When the user clicks next step, jQuery slides in the next page.  I would like that page to be (www.xyz.com/form-2).

I know websites like hypem.com do this, I'm just looking for an elegant way to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the way to do this is by updating browser history for each of the steps.  Take a look at the [History plugin for jQuery](http://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin)